# Can't access column in different tab of same form

Tags: sapb1

When I use following code it's showing invalid column. Column index is correct.

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Zcx.jpg)

I have called oMatrix in main form and matrix of different tab but of same form is needed whose matrix id is different

Comment: Please Provide some sample code so we can better understand your issue.

Comment: What does the output of pval.ItemUID show in a message box? Also where is oMatrix assigned?